# JButton como pegar o Text do Botão dentro de evento

Tags: java, eclipse, jbutton

Olá necessito criar n JButtons, o critério de criação é uma tabela no banco de dados que tem n itens. Tenho que criar um botão para cada item e quando der um clique no botão ele tem que me mostrar uma mensagem do número daquele item. Criar o botão foi fácil, porém não sei como criar esses métodos.

```
    int qtd=cartela.qtdCartelas();
                    JToggleButton btn[] = new JToggleButton[qtd];


                    for(int i=0;i<qtd;i++)
                    {
                        numeroBotao.next();
                        btn[i]=new JToggleButton(numeroBotao.getString(1));
                        panel.add(btn[i]);
                        System.out.println();

                    }


Ao clicar no botão necessito gerar um evento.

Conseguir fazer isso:



for(int   i=0;i<qtd;i++)
                {
                    //Cria os actionListener dos botões. 
                    btn[i].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        //Necessito pegar o Texto do botão ou a posição dele no vetor
                        int l = Integer.parseInt(btn[i].getText()); 

                        //

                    }
                    });
                }
```

Comment: O actionPerformed no final do código não funciona? Qual o problema dele? Lembrando que você está usando JToggleButton, são um pouco diferentes dos JButtons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Porque você faz 2 fors? não poderia adicionar os ActionListeners no mesmo for para popular o vetor? Assim você nem precisaria desse vetor. Alem disso, nesse código:

```
int l = Integer.parseInt(btn[i].getText());
```

como você já tem como parâmetro o ActionEvent, você pode simplesmente usar:

```
int l = Integer.parseInt(e.getSource().getText());
```

e caso der erro, caste para JToggleButton:

```
int l = Integer.parseInt((JToggleButton)(e.getSource()).getText());
```

Edit:

Código completo (mais ou menos)

```
 int qtd = cartela.qtdCartelas();

 for (int i = 0; i < qtd; i++) {
  numeroBotao.next();
  JToggleButton botao = new JToggleButton(numeroBotao.getString(1));
  botao.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    //Necessito pegar o Texto do botão ou a posição dele no vetor
    int l = Integer.parseInt((JToggleButton)(e.getSource()).getText());

    //

   }
  });
  panel.add(botao);
  System.out.println();

 }
```

Comment: Pode adicionar como ficaria o laço com as mudanças sugeridas? A resposta está boa, só falta isso pra ficar completa :)